# I need a suggestion about jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery

**Code:**

```
$(element).click(function() {
jQuery.ajax(
type: 'GET',
url: 'file.php?id=xxx',
async: false,
success: function(data) {
...
}
);
});
```

**file.php** do a select on database and it will show about 500.000 lines.

I need to do a progressbar(0 - 100%) while ajax get these lines.

does anyone have any suggestions?

maybe should I use an `iframe` to do it? I don't know if it's possible to do with ajax.

Comment: Are you trying to crash your server? :)

Comment: Assuming you're just asking "how should I implement a progress bar", Forget AJAX. Worship the holyness that is pure jQuery. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

Comment: don't specify `async: false,` that makes it synchronous, not Ajax. Synchronous is usually bad because it makes browser freeze until request completes.

Answer (score 0):

You should send more ajax requests to be able to show progress, it isn't possible with single one

Comment: u mean that i should do more than 1 jQuery.ajax call?

Comment: yes. For example 10 of them and after one is done, make progressbar 10% and so on...

Answer (score 0):

On your server, you'll need to implement a function that takes a given id (and user id or user ip address), and returns the current status of the given request.  This is entirely dependent on how you do your SQL or other server-side activity, but it's a core concept in understanding "what percent is done on my activity?".

That said, let's say to implement *"file.php?request=status&id=..."* which returns a JSON struct *{ :status => "0.50" }* to imply 50% completed on the task.  Sorry again that I cannot help with this portion, but it's up to your specific code on the server as how best to implement this.

Once you kick off your AJAX (as above), set a time to occasionally ping your server with updates.

```
$('#progressBar').progressBar( 'value', 0 );

var updateProgressBar = function() {
  $.ajax({
           'type': get,
           'url': 'file.php?request=status&id=...', 
           'success': function(json) { $('#progressBar').progressBar( 'value', json.status * 100 ); }
};

var updater = setTimeout(updateProgressBar, 2000); //make sure to clear this when request completes
```

Hopefully this will set you on the way to implementing a proper progress bar and let me know if you have any questions with the implementation or ideas.

Comment: it isn't possible as you can'T see % of rows loaded (selected)

Comment: Can you reasonably split your queries into steps without a loss in performance?  E.g. if you just selecting 500,000 rows, can you grab 10,000 at a time?  Alternatively, if your query doesn't adjust much, you could keep a running average (by input variable) or completion time.